# GCM "Topic Messaging" doesn't deliver to all of the subscribers

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We use GCM to send a message to a specific topic, e.g. `/topics/weather`. But we see unexpected behavior from GCM. Using some repeated tests we find these:

- It delivers to devices randomly (Meaning it doesn't deliver to some devices at all)
- Delivery is delayed (for long times) on some devices

Has anyone had the same issue and somehow managed to find the solution?  Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: How many subscribers does your app have? Topic messaging is limited to 1M devices per app (if you have that many users, you are doing well :)).

Comment: @Eran No. I test it with only 3K users and yet experiencing unreliable results.

Comment: It is possible that some of your devices are offline, so the messages only delivered, when the devices are online again.

Comment: @ztan  that's not the case too.  I test it several times,   at different times,  and experienceing the same results.